# Java Desktop Application on Network basis

Tags: java, swing, networking, user-interface, ip-address

Is it possible for a Java Desktop Application coded with java Swing to use in multiple computer through networking? I have a Java Desktop Application with MySQL as database. I want to deployed it in about 3-5 computers by means of Networking or sending data depend on their IP Address. SO what are the process that i am going to do to achieve this networking. Is setting the path of the database inside my program into the server's IP Address will help? Thank you so much.

Comment: That is really unclear. What do you mean by "sending data depend on their IP Address"?

Comment: I mean Computer networking. Computer Networking  allows computers to exchange data. I want to network my system using router. So multiple computers can use my system and any of them can insert,retrieve,delete,update the database.

Comment: I know what networking is, and that does not answer my question. What is the dependency on the IP address?

Comment: Could your rephrase you question? You mean that you want to provide access to  database's data depending on IP address.

Comment: I mean in networking you have to know the IP Address of each computer so how am i going to network my system using router?

Comment: Set up one of the computers as a DNS server.

Comment: For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.  If the launch file (XML with a JNLP extension) is generated dynamically, properties can be added on a client per client basis.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for a Java Desktop Application coded with java Swing to use in multiple computer through networking?

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

> .. sending data depend on their IP Address

If the launch file (XML with a JNLP extension) is generated dynamically, properties can be added on a client by client basis.  Alternately, have the client supply that information when they 'phone home'.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the hostName in your database connections from localhost with the IP adress of the computer carrying the Database.